# BackButton title disappering when navigationItem.title too long

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, autolayout

All my buttons in a NavigationItem are set in code for a specific view in the viewHierachy.
 The title is set with a titleLabel to set minimumScaleFactor and contentCompression to it:

```
titleLabel.text = self.bookTitel;
titleLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5;
[titleLabel setContentCompressionResistancePriority:UILayoutPriorityDefaultLow
                             forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal];
[titleLabel setContentCompressionResistancePriority:UILayoutPriorityDefaultLow
                             forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical];
self.navigationItem.titleView = titleLabel;
```

Now when the bookTitle is too long it is shortened with ..., but the backButtons title disappears too.

`UIBarButtonItem` doesn't respond to `setContentCompression:` so I can't set it to requiredPriority.

How can I prevent the backButton from not showing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is an extract from the Overview section of the [UINavigationItem class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationItem_Class/Reference/UINavigationItem.html):

> The navigation item must provide a title to display when the view
>   controller is topmost on the navigation stack. In addition, the item
>   may contain additional buttons to display on the right side of the
>   navigation bar. You can specify buttons and views to display on the
>   left side of the toolbar using the leftBarButtonItems property but the
>   navigation controller displays those buttons only if there is space
>   available.

If there isn't enough space, the navigation controller won't display any buttons on the left hand side, where your back button is. That's up to the navigation controller...

**To prevent the backButton from not showing:**

Can you restrict the size of `titleLabel` further? (The size of the view).

Comment: Hm, actually minimumScaleFactor and the contentCompressions seems to be ignored. Setting the views frame too. I worked around by cutting the title when it is too long.